# How long should I wait for a letter after completing Innocence Lost?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I completed Innocence Lost but haven't received any letter. Is it a glitch or should I keep waiting?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I've slept 24 hours in every inn in Skyrim and still no letter. I've also done miscellaneous quests (word walls, bounties, etc.) and still no letter or abduction.

Comment: The only game where you are sad because you aren't being kidnapped...

Answer (score 7):

Go to sleep in any bed in Skyrim.

Comment: yup, you don't need to wait for the letter, just sleep

Answer (score 5):

You have to return to Aventis Aretino in Windhelm and tell him Grelod is dead.  THEN sleep in a bed and you will be kidnapped.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to receive the letter to join the Brotherhood, from [the wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Dark_Brotherhood):

> Within a few days, a courier will deliver a letter to you. In some instances you can simply sleep in a bed for 24 hours, and you will wake up in Astrid's captivity. The letter should be a black hand print, with the words "We know" underneath it. You must then sleep in any bed to be kidnapped by Astrid. **It is possible to sleep and be kidnapped before receiving the letter and if this is the case, you will never receive the letter but will still be able to join the Dark Brotherhood**. If you sleep in a bed you will be kidnapped and will awake instantly in a locked cabin. Here, you will meet Astrid, a Brotherhood member, who tells you that by killing Grelod, you stole a Brotherhood contract, which must be repaid.

So now that Grelod is dead, you need to find a bed to sleep in, even though you did not receive the letter.

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to know how to join the darkbrother hood this is how i did it. I was at the whiterun stables and there is a cart were you can go to riften(cause it's faster) You can go to any of the carages. And then go back to whiterun and go to windhelm. And find aventi's residence. And unlock it with a lock pick(it is novice so it should be easy. Complete the quest innocent lose. And find the neaest bed. You must sleep for at least 8 hours. You should be kidnapped by this lady and she'll tell you to kill someone. Then continue on.

Answer (score -1):

You have to tell Aventis that you killed her and then a courier should come and give you a letter with a black hand print

Answer (score -2):

Die two times and then go to Whiterun and sleep in the fifth room of the Inn. It's a glitch that sometimes happens.

Comment: How does dieing changes anything? When you die, you reload, and you are back to the same state as before. Also, why specifically the fifth room? Is there even five room in this inn?